# My website isn't scrolling, what should i do?

Tags: css, scroll, hidden, portfolio

I am working on my portfolio page and as I was writing my html and my css, the site wasn't scrolling. I can't see the code only the first section.

Here is the html:

```
<navbar id="navbar">
          <a href="#" title=""><img id="logo" src="imagini/portfolio.png" alt="my portfolio" title="Bogdan's portfolio" /></a>
          <ul type="none" id="list">
              <a href="#" title=""><li>works</li></a>
              <a href="#" title=""><li>about</li></a>
              <a href="#" title=""><li>contact</li></a>

          </ul>


       </div>
       <section id="welcome-section">
          <h1>HI, I'M<br /> Pavel Bogdan Mihail</h1>
          <p>I make people get amazed by my works because I'm AWSOME!</p>

          <button type="button">GET IN TOUCH</button>

       </section>
       
       <section id="about">
        <h3>A little bit about me</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis neque sed massa sollicitudin interdum. Pellentesque vel libero sollicitudin lectus sollicitudin consectetur. In dictum eu nisi id porta. Ut molestie luctus hendrerit. Nulla ac nisl sit amet urna molestie dictum. Phasellus et turpis aliquet dolor iaculis congue. Nulla eget ligula nibh. Maecenas vel aliquam quam, sit amet semper nibh. Sed consectetur malesuada mauris a posuere. Suspendisse semper, magna ac convallis faucibus, orci eros ultrices diam, ac porttitor enim sem eget lorem. Proin laoreet commodo arcu, nec lobortis felis dapibus quis. Aenean ut arcu mauris. Nunc tempus erat eu felis faucibus facilisis. Donec gravida ullamcorper dolor ac dapibus. Sed pellentesque dapibus neque, quis ornare purus tincidunt ac.</p>
         
       </section>
```

here is a codepen edit: https://codepen.io/bogdan-pavel/pen/pobgWjg

Answer (score 1):

Your navbar is missing a closing tag. If you ad `</navbar>` after the navbar is done the rest will scroll.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to close the </navbar> tag. Thank you. It is scrolling now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<navbar id="navbar">
          <a href="#" title=""><img id="logo" src="imagini/portfolio.png" alt="my portfolio" title="Bogdan's portfolio" /></a>
          <ul type="none" id="list">
              <a href="#" title=""><li>works</li></a>
              <a href="#" title=""><li>about</li></a>
              <a href="#" title=""><li>contact</li></a>

          </ul>


       </div>
       <section id="welcome-section">
          <h1>HI, I'M<br /> Pavel Bogdan Mihail</h1>
          <p>I make people get amazed by my works because I'm AWSOME!</p>

          <button type="button">GET IN TOUCH</button>

       </section>
       
       <section id="about">
        <h3>A little bit about me</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis neque sed massa sollicitudin interdum. Pellentesque vel libero sollicitudin lectus sollicitudin consectetur. In dictum eu nisi id porta. Ut molestie luctus hendrerit. Nulla ac nisl sit amet urna molestie dictum. Phasellus et turpis aliquet dolor iaculis congue. Nulla eget ligula nibh. Maecenas vel aliquam quam, sit amet semper nibh. Sed consectetur malesuada mauris a posuere. Suspendisse semper, magna ac convallis faucibus, orci eros ultrices diam, ac porttitor enim sem eget lorem. Proin laoreet commodo arcu, nec lobortis felis dapibus quis. Aenean ut arcu mauris. Nunc tempus erat eu felis faucibus facilisis. Donec gravida ullamcorper dolor ac dapibus. Sed pellentesque dapibus neque, quis ornare purus tincidunt ac.</p>
         
       </section>
<navbar>
```